# AnyChart Remove range markers from plot

Tags: javascript, anychart

I cannot find any information on how to delete `rangeMarker` from my stock chart plots.
I do not wish to enable or disabled them, they need to be fully removed.
Preferably not using a work-around such as navigating through the anycharts objects instead of using defined methods.

Set `rangeMarkers`:

```
    // settings is an array that contains all the ranges
    settings.forEach(range => {
        range.text = "";

        plot.rangeMarker(settings.indexOf(range, 0))
            .from(range.min).to(range.max)
            .fill(range.color, 0.2);
});
```

I tried overwriting the markers, but since the scale of these markers are completely different this will leave markers which shouldn't be on the graph.

Comment: I have since found that disposing the whole plot and initializing a new one works. However I would like to fix the problem at its source